R3F / ThreeJs - PlayerController distanceFactor problem
I'm using pmndrs/ecctrl for first person movement. I have placed some HTML tooltips in the scene, but the distanceFactor does not seem to work as intended. The reason is probably that the collider does not rotate when moving the mouse. Does anyone have experience with the player controller and can help?
See Screencast: https://imgur.com/a/DbyGf5v
My Player:
<KeyboardControls map={keyboardMap}>
        <Ecctrl
          renderOrder={renderOrder}
          canJump={false}
          capsuleHalfHeight={0.6}
          floatHeight={0.6}
          position={position}
          camInitDir={cameraPos} // Camera initial rotation direction (in radians)
          camCollision={false} // disable camera collision detect (useless in FP mode)
          camInitDis={-0.01} // camera intial position
          camMinDis={-0.01} // camera zoom in the closest position
          camFollowMult={1000} // give a big number here, so the camera follows the target (character) instantly
          camLerpMult={1000} // give a big number here, so the camera lerp to the followCam position instantly
          turnVelMultiplier={1} // Turning speed same as moving speed
          dampingC={0.1}
          autoBalance={false}
          maxVelLimit={2.5}
          jumpVel={0} // disable jump
          floatingDis={1.5} // Set higher view-point
          turnSpeed={100} // give it big turning speed to prevent turning wait time
          mode={'CameraBasedMovement'} 
        />
 </KeyboardControls>

My Tooltip:
 {hovered && (
          <Html
            center
            position={tooltipPosition.toArray()}
            distanceFactor={8}
            style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
            <Label title={'Lasercutter'} content={'Click to open'} />
          </Html>
        )}

